# How to create connection pooling in java example

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

The file `db.properties` contains url, username and password.

My sample code:

```
Properties DBProperties = new Properties();
Connection con = null;

DBProperties.load(
    new FileInputStream(
        System.getenv("Connection") + File.separator + "java" + File.separator + "properties" + File.separator + "db.properties"
    )
);

logger.info("DB url: " + DBProperties.getProperty("DBURL"));
logger.info("DB username: " + DBProperties.getProperty("DBUserName"));
logger.info("DB password: " + DBProperties.getProperty("DBPassword"));
```

Comment: Do you want to implement your own connection pool or just use an existing one?

Comment: Use a dedicated library

Comment: @dsp_user my own connection pool.

Comment: Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37128603/is-singleton-not-good-for-get-jdbc-connection-any-good-implementation-of-connec/37133098#37133098

Comment: Which jar uses in that project..? Name it...

Comment: No dependecies are required (no jars) for that project.