# Getting connection from Connection Pool taking too much time in java

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection

I have a java based web application in which I have included the Connection Pooling method.

Code is as follows :

```
public final class Database {
    private static final String SQL_EXIST = "show tables;";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    private static final BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

    static {
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://link");
        dataSource.setUsername("user");
        dataSource.setPassword("pass");
        dataSource.setMaxTotal(10);
    }

    private Database() {
        //
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }
}
```

Now in my application whenever I need a connection, I use `Database.getConnection()`. Issue is that, whenever am calling `Database.getConnection()`, it's taking around 900 ms .

Am also closing the connection after every DB operation.

Code which I used is :

```
System.out.println("Time before callingg Func is : "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-main_time));
ABC a=new ABC();    
count = a.d(Database.getConnection(), jObj.getString("a"), jObj.getString("b"),c,jObj.getString("d"),jObj.getString("e"));
System.out.println("Time after callingg Func is : "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-main_time));
```

Output which I get is :

```
Time before callingg Func is : 61
sql Query time is : 266
Time after callingg Func is : 1123
```

**EDIT :**

I calculated the time when conn is not closed.

I also added a timestamp before going into the db function and a timestamp in the first line of the function. Then I calculated the time from 2nd line to the end of the function which is actually sql time.

```
Time before callingg Func is : 68 and time in ms is : 1490001506121
Time in ms when inside function is : 1490001506843
Diff in time is : 722
sql Query time is : 260
Time after callingg Func is : 1050
```

**EDIT 2**

Removed the connection part from the function i.e.

```
count = a.d(jObj.getString("a"), jObj.getString("b"),c,jObj.getString("d"),jObj.getString("e"));
```

and then the time calculations are :

```
Time before callingg Func is : 65 and time in ms is : 1490003211049
Time in ms when inside function is : 1490003211049
Diff in time is : 0
sql Query time is : 1
Time after callingg Func is : 66
```

Comment: Why not just open a connection pool and not to close after each connection. User permission is verified at your logic and the connections use a single application account.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938517/closing-jdbc-connections-in-pool This link says that we should always close a connection. Having said that, I also tried without closing the connection. It still takes the same amount of time.

Comment: You didn't read your quoted post carefully. In the accepted post it said explicitly that calling `close()`on a pooled connection only return the connection to the pool. I also doubt you measure the time correctly by claiming that without closing connection it takes same amount of time.

Comment: To me it looks like you are measuring roundtrip time of `a.d(...` call, not only the `getConnection`. And we completely do not see how you measure "sql Query time" ... there could be a lot other stuff going on there, too.

Comment: Please check the edit. I added the timestamp whne conn is not closed. @Fildor, am creating a variable as `long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();` and then at the end, just before retuen am printing `System.out.println("sql Query time is : "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime));`

Comment: Still you have the `jObj.getString` calls that may also need some time. Just assuming they are fast is not enough when blaming the pool.

Comment: @Fildor, I was sure but then just to show the numbers, I removed the connection part from the function and then ran the function. You can see that the time taken is 0. So `jObj.getString`, doesnt really takes time but connection does.

Comment: Just because you set setMaxTotal to 10 connections, it doesn't mean that they have actually been  created. Use getNumActive to see how many active connections are currently in the pool.

Comment: @dsp_user, number of active connections are 4-5. I printed that before calling the DB function.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure why it's taking so long. I've written a simple implementation of a connection pool (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37128603/is-singleton-not-good-for-get-jdbc-connection-any-good-implementation-of-connec/37133098#37133098) so maybe you can take a look. I basically get a DB connection either from the DriverManager or DataSource but store all the connections within my pool. It works pretty well, at least for  simple applications.